# How do I read files in a subdirectory/prefix from google cloud storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, prefix

I have moved files and folders over to google cloud storage (GCS). I am finding it difficult to understand the prefixes and delimiters in the GCS documentation.

What I want to do is essentially replace the path/location of locally stored files with GCS location. E.g.

It is currently coded for local path:

```
Variable = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Folder1\\doc3.csv"
```

I need it written to search for the file in GCS like below:

```
Variable = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/MYBUCKETNAME/Folder1/doc3.csv?supportedpurview=project"
```

This obviously doesn't work but I have the below code which connects to the bucket but I am struggling to direct it to the specific file.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('mybucketname')
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='Folder1')
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

So the output of this gives the following files in that specific folder:

```
doc1.csv
doc2.csv
doc3.csv
```

For my variable, what do I write as my filepath to doc3.csv. This is what I am struggling with.

Comment: do you want check the content of a folder? or download a folder?

Comment: Well the issue I have at the moment is I don't know how to point my variable "MonthlyCount" to the .csv file in my bucket. The .csv file is located in a subfolder within the bucket e.g. mybucketname/folder1/count.csv. I have managed to solve my first problem which was to point my directories to the correct path i.e. `home_dir = client.bucket('mybucketname')
data_dir = home_dir.list_blobs(prefix='Reference Data')`

Comment: Can you add more details? What are your input files? Do you need to output back to Cloud Storage as well, or just read from it?

Comment: @DustinIngram I've written out my above query again, hope this makes it clear!

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to a blob in Cloud Storage by it's name like it's a local file. You'll need to transfer the file from Cloud Storage to your local filesystem first:

```py
destination_file_name = ...
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

Then you can read the file from where you've stored it locally:

```py
with open(destination_file_name) as f:
   contents = f.read()
```

...or otherwise use it like any other local file on your filesystem.

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects for more details.

Comment: so there's not a way to read files directly from GCS and i'd have to download it locally first? I would prefer not to download it and read directly from GCS if there is a way.

Comment: Correct. Even if you could "read directly from GCS", it would still require transferring the data in the file from GCS to wherever your script is running, so there's not much difference.